# silverstripe-graphql mutations using alternate ID

Tags: php, graphql, silverstripe-4

I'm attempting to write a GraphQL mutation to do updates. In this application, a DataObject called QuickPossession contains a second ID which corresponds to a 3rd-party database. I need to update QuickPossessions according to that second ID. Here is the model:

```
<?php
namespace Organization\HomeBuilderSite\DataObjects;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\GraphQL\Scaffolding\Interfaces\ScaffoldingProvider;
use SilverStripe\GraphQL\Scaffolding\Scaffolders\SchemaScaffolder;

class QuickPossession extends DataObject implements ScaffoldingProvider {
  private static $table_name = 'QuickPossession';

  private static $db = [
    'SecondID' => 'Int',
    'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'Address' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'SquareFeet' => 'Int',
  ];

  public function provideGraphQLScaffolding(SchemaScaffolder $scaffolder) {
    $scaffolder
      ->type(QuickPossession::class)
        ->addFields([
          'SecondID', 
          'ID',
          'Title',
          'Address', 
          'SquareFeet'
        ])
        ->operation(SchemaScaffolder::CREATE)
          ->end()
        ->operation(SchemaScaffolder::READ)
          ->end()
        ->operation(SchemaScaffolder::UPDATE)
          ->end()
        ->end();
    return $scaffolder;
  }
}
```

And in my `mysite.yml`

```
SilverStripe\GraphQL\Controller:
  schema:
    scaffolding_providers:
      - Organization\HomeBuilderSite\DataObjects\QuickPossession
```

I am able to successfully run the following mutation:

```
mutation UpdateQuickPossession($ID: ID!, $Input: QuickPossessionUpdateInputType!) {
    updateQuickPossession(ID: $ID, Input: $Input) {
        Title
    }
}
```

With these variables:

```
{
    "ID": "3",
    "Input": {
        "Title": "Example Home Name",
        "Address": "123 Smith Street"
    }
}
```

Which correctly gives this output:

```
{
    "data": {
        "updateQuickPossession": {
            "Title": "Example Home Name"
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same using the SecondID as the unique identifier. I've tried the following:

```
mutation UpdateQuickPossession($ID: SecondID!, $Input: QuickPossessionUpdateInputType!) {
    updateQuickPossession(SecondID: $ID, Input: $Input) {
        Title
    }
}
```

With these variables:

```
{
    "SecondID": "1457",
    "Input": {
        "Title": "Example Home Name",
        "Address": "123 Smith Street"
    }
}
```

Which produces this error:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unknown type \"SecondID\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 37
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "message": "Unknown argument \"SecondID\" on field \"updateQuickPossession\" of type \"Mutation\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 24
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "message": "Field \"updateQuickPossession\" argument \"ID\" of type \"ID!\" is required but not provided.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is this: do mutations only work with the primary ID? Is it possible to use alternate unique identifiers?

Or am I missing something else? Perhaps this is a limitation of using the  scaffold approach to setting DataObjects up for GraphQL queries? Many thanks :)

I've been referring to the [silverstripe-graphql](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql) and [graphql.org](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to do this using `SchemaScaffolder::UPDATE`, but I was able to write an *arbitrary* mutation as per the [silverstripe-graphql](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql#adding-arbitrary-queries-and-mutations) documentation.

```
<?php
namespace Organization\HomeBuilderSite\Pages;

use Organization\HomeBuilderSite\Page;
use SilverStripe\GraphQL\Scaffolding\Interfaces\ScaffoldingProvider;
use SilverStripe\GraphQL\Scaffolding\Scaffolders\SchemaScaffolder;

class QuickPossession extends Page implements ScaffoldingProvider {
  private static $table_name = 'QuickPossession';
  private static $db = [
    'SecondID' => 'Varchar(30)',
    'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'Address' => 'Varchar(255)',
    'SquareFeet' => 'Int',
  ];

  public function provideGraphQLScaffolding(SchemaScaffolder $scaffolder) {
    $scaffolder
      // Setting up QuickPossessions for queries
      ->type(QuickPossession::class)
        ->addFields([
          'SecondID', 
          'ID',
          'Title',
          'Address', 
          'SquareFeet',
          'Community'
        ])
        ->operation(SchemaScaffolder::READ)
          ->end()

      ->mutation('updateQuickPossession', QuickPossession::class)
        ->addArgs([
          'SecondID' => 'ID!',
          'Title' => 'String',
        ])
        ->setResolver(function ($obj, $args, $context) {
          $item = QuickPossession::get()->filter('SecondID',$args['SecondID'])->first();
          $item->SecondID = $args['SecondID'];
          $item->Title = $args['Title'];
          $item->write();
          return $item;
        })
        ->end();
    return $scaffolder;
  }
```

And then I can run a mutation with:

```
mutation UpdateQuickPossession($SecondID: ID!, $Title: String) {
    updateQuickPossession(SecondID: $SecondID, Title: $Title) {
            ID
            SecondID
            Title
            SquareFeet
            Address
    }
}
```

With query variables:

```
{
    "SecondID": "1",
    "Title": "Clarkson"
}
```

Which successfully gives me:

```
{
    "data": {
        "updateQuickPossession": {
            "ID": "9",
            "SecondID": "1",
            "Title": "Clarkson",
            "SquareFeet": 2123,
            "Address": "123 Smith Rd"
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the custom `mutation()` is required in order to override the use of `ID` as the primary identifier. The only drawback thus far is that it's not clear to me how to define and use complex input types (ie. `$Input: QuickPossessionUpdateInputType!`) in this method.